# Writing to a folder with 777

Tags: php, apache, unix, ubuntu

My permissions are set to 777 but I still cant upload to the folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 web58 client1 45056 Nov 15 15:33 upload
```

I've tried `is_writable()` which returns false.

Is there a reason why PHP cant write to the folder?

Comment: What are the permissions on the parent directories?

Comment: Chris all parent directories are 777 also

Comment: What OS specifically (i.e. distro)? There could be a few issues with things like SELinux or other permissions that prevent writing.

Comment: Also, can you write to an existing file with the permissions set to 777? Also, if you try to just write, what error do you get (Could show if the issue is open_basedir vs permission denied)?

Comment: [Here is a definition of what the columns are.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean), That would be file size.

Comment: Is it just PHP that can't write to the folder? Can you drop a new file in there outside of the web/PHP?

Answer (score 1):

If the limitation comes from PHP itself (and not the OS), it should be because of your `open_basedir` php.ini setting.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: Thanks, Ive checked and this is not set, so it must not be this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change a owner for this catalog (it helps me when I have some troubles with access to particular folder/subfolders).

You can use `chown` in your terminal:

```
chown -R ftpuser:ftpusergroup /catalog
```

Where `ftpuser` it will be user you use to connect with FTP (if you have problems with your FTP, or other user which you use to upload data), and `ftpusergroup` for this users group. `-R` makes `ftpuser:ftpusergroup` as owner for all subdirectories/files in chosen catalog.

To list users in your machine type:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

You can check to which group your user belongs with:

```
groups ftpuser
```

Answer for updated question: it is a size of given catalog/file.